# Why are my Google Fonts not showing up on mobile devices?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, fonts

On my website, http://jimbrink.org, I make use of the Roboto Slab font. (Actually, I have adapted a template, so that template makes use of the Roboto Slab font.)

I have noticed that the font doesn't show up on mobile browsers. But I don't understand why that is.

Every font call in the style.default.css file is to Roboto Slab. I've tested the site on an iOS device and an Android (Chrome browser).

EDIT: My css stylesheet can be found here: http://www.jimbrink.org/css/style.default.css

It was too long to post in the body of this post.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the site and inspecting the source I see that sometimes you specify your Google fonts with single quotes, and others double quotes. I've run into issues with this in the past and have defaulted to using double quotes, although looking at my compiled css it looks like the quotes are removed from the declarations.

I'd try using double quotes like `font-family: "Roboto Slab";` and see if this works. I'm not sure why this causes issues, and can't test your code at the moment,  but I hope this helps. If not, post your css and I'll try to take a look when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML (from Google Fonts) it says: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700,100%7CRoboto:400,700,300,100

Perhaps try: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab